# Why does MSTest and TestDriven.NET behave differently using this code?

Tags: frameworks, tdd, mstest, testdriven.net

Check out this code:

```
internal static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<IModel>> typeToCreator = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IModel>>();
protected static object _lock;        


public virtual void Register<T>(Func<IModel> creator)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
    if (typeToCreator.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        typeToCreator[typeof(T)] = creator;
    else
        typeToCreator.Add(typeof(T), creator);
    }
}
```

When I use run the code in this test (testframework is MSTest):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Must_Be_BasePresenterType()
{
     var sut = new ListTilbudPresenter(_tilbudView);
     Assert.IsInstanceOfType(sut, typeof(BasePresenter));
}
```

...MSTest passes it and TestDriven.NET fails it because _lock is null.

Why does MSTest NOT fail the test???

Comment: I don't see any call to register in your test code - when does it get called?